# AWK - if file is not found, display "not found"

Tags: unix

Trying to print "Not found" using awk

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
latestlogfilename=$(echo $latestlogline | awk 'END {print} { if (!NF) print "file not found" }')
echo "LATEST LOG = $(echo $latestlogline)"
echo "COUNT = $(wc -l $latestlogfilename)"
```

OUTPUT:

```
LATEST LOG = 24003651 Jun 8 14:17 /dir/foo.tx 
wc: 24003651: No such file or directory
wc: Jun: No such file or directory
wc: 8: No such file or directory
wc: 14:17: No such file or directory
COUNT =    51877 /dir/foo.tx
   51877 total
ls: cannot access /dir/foo2.tx: No such file or directory
LATEST LOG =
wc: file: No such file or directory
wc: not: No such file or directory
wc: found: No such file or directory
COUNT = 0 total
```

It does work but it's processing every line. I just want it to print "file not found" if the file isn't there, and if file is found, just display the latest log and count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not completely clear what you want, but maybe this will get you pointed in the right direction.

```
filename=$(echo $latestlogline | awk '{print $5}')
if [ -e "$filename" ]; then
  echo "COUNT = $(wc -l "$filename")"
else
  echo "file not found"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! Pointed me at the right direction indeed. :)